# Trying to replace string using Powershell regex

Tags: regex, powershell

My text file is as below

```
( HOST = <something numeric> )
```

Want to replace HOST value. So trying with below regx but no go

```
(Get-Content C:\Go\test.txt).replace("\HOST\s*=\s*.+\s*\", " HOST = 8888 ") | Set-Content C:\Go\test.txt
```

Any help?

Comment: The regex should be `"HOST\s*=\s*\d+\s*"`. But use `-replace`

Comment: I have to use get-content and set-content as using -replace changing format of file and causing issue. Basically I am trying to replace values to tnsnames.ora file and I can achieve that using ```cat "C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora" | %{$_ -replace "\(HOST\s*=\s*.+\s*\)\(", "(HOST = $hostname_container )("} >  "C:\tmp\tnsnames.ora"``` 
The value is getting replaced but causing issue during connection

Comment: If your file is binary, then I doubt you may use a regex. It only operates on the string content.

Comment: What kind of issue do you get duing connection when have replaced the name with PowerSell ?

Comment: Ok, I found: [*since ORA files used with Oracle Database are in fact just text files, you could technically convert them to any other text-based format, like HTML, TXT, PDF, etc.*](https://www.lifewire.com/ora-file-2622117). So, the only problem is how you *save* the file back. My solution below is valid, just you need to find the right way to read in and save the file. Does the `.ora` file have UTF8 with BOM or any other encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you use a regex replacement with the following regex:

```
PS> $s = "( HOST = 111111 )"
PS> $s -replace "HOST\s*=\s*\d+\s*", " HOST = 8888 "
(  HOST = 8888 )
```

Here, `HOST\s*=\s*\d+\s*` matches:

- `HOST` - a literal `HOST` string
- `\s*=\s*` - a `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `\d+`  -  1 or more digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.

If the *.ora file is UTF8 encoding without BOM, you need to use

```
$MyPath = 'C:\Go\test.txt'
$MyFile = Get-Content $MyPath
$MyFile = $MyFile -replace "HOST\s*=\s*\d+\s*", " HOST = 8888 "
$Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($MyPath, $MyFile, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)
```

Comment: again, I am able to do that with -replace - ```cat "C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\‌​tnsnames.ora" | %{$_ -replace "\(HOST\s*=\s*.+\s*\)\(", "(HOST = $hostname_container )("} > "C:\tmp\tnsnames.ora"``` (I am actually replacing values to tnsnames.ora) but this causing issue during connection. When run get-context | set-content, value is getting replaced and connection is working fine. I am only trying to manage that replace with regx

Comment: @mansingshinde Glad it worked. If the answer proved helpful and informative to you, please also consider upvoting.